# How to get SAP CloudSdk BatchRequest not to ignore filter parameter on Batch Query?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, batch-query

We are currently struggeling with Batch Query,
which seems to ignore the filter expressions on S4 side caused by a wrong URL encoding.

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZP2M_A_CONTRACT_SEARCH_HDR_CDS/ZP2M_A_CONTRACT_SEARCH_HDR?$filter=PurchaseContractID eq %274600002020%27&$select=*&$format=json
```

Executing the query using `FluentHelperRead.execute(HttpClient)`
the returned list of entities contains the expected result with exactly one entity.

Executing the query as Batch Query the following request is logged in console:

```
GET ZP2M_A_CONTRACT_SEARCH_HDR?%24filter%3DPurchaseContractID+eq+%25274600002020%2527%26%24select%3D*%26%24format%3Djson HTTP/1.1
```

The collected list from all batch result parts contains all entities.

It seems, that the query URL is encoded in wrong way

and that S4 ignored the filter expressions when encoded in this way.

e.g. `$filter` is encoded to `%24filter` which is ignored by S4.

This seems to be a bug in `BatchRequestImpl.getRequest(ODataQueryImpl)` method,
where URL encoding is done a 2nd time on already encoded URL parts.

```
if(systemQuery.indexOf("$format=json&$count=true") != -1)
{
    systemQuery = systemQuery.substring(0, systemQuery.indexOf("$format=json&$count=true") -1);
    keysUrl.append("/$count");
}
systemQuery = URLEncoder.encode(systemQuery, "UTF-8"); // this code line which encodes the query 2nd time
keysUrl.append("?");
```

The code line `systemQuery = URLEncoder.encode(systemQuery, "UTF-8");` located in

  BatchRequestImpl(1.38.0) - line 295

  BatchRequestImpl(1.42.2) - line 307

encodes the systemQuery string again (including the already encoded parts of FilterExpression as well).

When undoing the changes of this code line in debugger and replacing the scapces by %20 or '+' the Batch Query looks like that

```
GET ZP2M_A_CONTRACT_SEARCH_HDR?$filter=PurchaseContractID%20eq%20%274600002020%27&$select=*&$format=json HTTP/1.1

GET ZP2M_A_CONTRACT_SEARCH_HDR?$filter=PurchaseContractID+eq+%274600002020%27&$select=*&$format=json HTTP/1.1
```

and it returns the expected result (exactly 1 entity).

This wrong encoding appears when using these library versions:

sdk-bom: 3.16.1

connectivity: 1.38.0

This issue appears in newest SDK versions as well:

sdk-bom: 3.21.0

connectivity: 1.39.0

This issue appears with connectivity JAR in newest version too:

sdk-bom: 3.21.0

connectivity: 1.40.2

Debugging together with a ABAP/S4 colleague figures out,

that S4 only applies filter expressions, if the keyword `$filter` is found in request,

`%24filter%3D` is ignored (the cause why we get all entities running the Batch Query).

My suggestion to solve it would be

```
// decode query first (to decode the filter expression)
systemQuery = URLDecoder.decode(systemQuery, "UTF_8");
// encode query
systemQuery = org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil.encodeQuery(systemQuery, "UTF_8");
```

My code, how I am calling the batchRequest:

```
FluentHelperRead<?, MyEntity, ?> queryApi = myService.getAll... // with adding some filter expression

BatchRequestBuilder batchRequestBuilder = BatchRequestBuilder.withService(MyService.DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH);
ODataQuery query = queryApi.toQuery();
batchRequestBuilder.addQueryRequest(query);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientAccessor
    .getHttpClient(DefaultErpHttpDestinationAccessor.get());
BatchRequest request = batchRequestBuilder.build();
BatchResult result = request.execute(httpClient);
// ... evaluate response
```

I think, this is a general issue in the Cloud SDK.

Would is be possible to get this fixed in next Cloud SDK release?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for such a quality bug report! We'll reproduce the issue shortly and will do our best to release a fix in the next SDK release. We have a bi-weekly release cadence, which means the next one is settled. After confirming, reproducing, and agreeing on the fix we'll update you on the release number it will be fixed with.

Comment: What's you deadline for this?

Comment: This issue affects my customer's production environment.
So it would be greate to have it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code for **Batch** request? Do you use `BatchRequestImpl` directly?

The thing is SAP Cloud SDK relies on some dependencies one of which introduces the `BatchRequestImpl` and if it's called directly the bug is on the dependency side. I have already informed them to investigate this double encoding issue. Unfortunately, we can't directly influence how fast it is resolved and sometimes it takes longer than we'd like.

The good news, we're working on replacing this dependency with our own implementation to solve exactly this kind of problem. The `batch` is work in progress and should be available in `Beta` around the end of next month for OData V4 and hopefully around the same time for OData V2 (it's not a hard commitment and depends on other priorities).

From here we have to wait for whatever happens first:

- The bug is fixed on the dependency side
- Internal OData client implementation is ready together with **Batch**

I hope it helps and explains current solution path. If you share a bit around your deadlines and the potential impact we'll be happy to consider that.

Comment: Hi Artyom!

I have added the code above, how I am calling the batch query.

Comment: Sounds good.
At my customer's environment we are using Odata V2.
So I hope, the Odata V2 solution will be available shortly after Odata V4.
Thanks for working on that.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for posting back the code snippet. It sheds a bit of lite, but I have to investigate further. We'll look for a workaround as well if this is not very quick to solve. I'll keep you posted about the progress.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed within the dependency and as of version `3.25.0` the SAP Cloud SDK includes the fix.

Comment: Thank you very much.
We will check and take over this fix.