# Odata Query Batch Request - Filter not working

Tags: odata, sap-cloud-sdk

We are using SAP SDK 3.25.0 and calling a batch request Read query passing some filters. I am getting the response of all the records and it can be seen that the filter is not working properly.

I have referred this blog [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549269/how-to-get-sap-cloudsdk-batchrequest-not-to-ignore-filter-parameter-on-batch-que?) but I am getting the same issue of decode URL issue `YY1_QuantityContractTracki?$filter=((CustomerName eq %27Ford%27) and (SalesSchedulingAgreement eq %270030000141%27)) and (PurchaseOrderByCustomer eq %27TEST%27)&$select=SalesSchedulingAgreement,PurchaseOrderByCustomer,Customer,CustomerName,SalesSchedulingAgreementItem,Material,MaterialByCustomer&$format=json`

Below is the query program which I am using.

Am I missing something here. Please let us know
Thanks,
Arun Pai

```
final BatchRequestBuilder builder = BatchRequestBuilder.withService("/sap/opu/odata/sap/YY1_QUANTITYCONTRACTTRACKI_CDS");
    for (Contract contract : contracts) {
        FilterExpression mainFilter = new FilterExpression("CustomerName", "eq", ODataType.of(contract.getCustomerName()))
                .and(new FilterExpression("SalesSchedulingAgreement", "eq", ODataType.of(contract.getSchAgrmntNo())))
                .and(new FilterExpression("PurchaseOrderByCustomer", "eq", ODataType.of(contract.getCustRefNo())));
        final ODataQuery oDataQuery = ODataQueryBuilder
                .withEntity(sapConfig.getEssentialsContractServiceUrl(),
                        sapConfig.getEssentialsContractListEntity())
                .select("SalesSchedulingAgreement", "PurchaseOrderByCustomer", "Customer", "CustomerName",
                        "SalesSchedulingAgreementItem", "Material", "MaterialByCustomer")
                .filter(mainFilter)
                .build();
        builder.addQueryRequest(oDataQuery);
    }
    final BatchRequest batchRequest = builder.build();
    final BatchResult batchResult = batchRequest.execute(httpClient);
```

**Update**

I have changed the version to 3.35.0 today with connectivity version 1.40.11 but it did'nt work either.
Below is the log request which gets printed in the console

---

2021-01-15 19:15:03.831  INFO 42640 --- [io-8084-exec-10] c.s.c.s.o.c.impl.BatchRequestImpl        : --batch_123
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET YY1_QuantityContractTracki?%24filter%3D%28%28CustomerName+eq+%2527Ford27%29+and+%28SalesSchedulingAgreement+eq+%25270030000141%2527%29%29+and+%28PurchaseOrderByCustomer+eq+%2527TEST%2527%29%26%24select%3DSalesSchedulingAgreement%2CPurchaseOrderByCustomer%2CCustomer%2CCustomerName%2CSalesSchedulingAgreementItem%2CMaterial%2CMaterialByCustomer%26%24format%3Djson HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose

--batch_123--

Comment: Did you test the OData URL directly with only one filter expression (e.g. `CustomerName`) and did it return something? If yes, what happens if you add another argument (e.g. `SalesSchedulingAgreement`)?

Comment: While calling the OData URL directly as below, there are no issues and can see the results  in the browser YY1_QuantityContractTracki?$filter=((CustomerName eq 'Ford') and (SalesSchedulingAgreement eq '0030000141')) and (PurchaseOrderByCustomer eq 'TEST')&$select=SalesSchedulingAgreement,PurchaseOrderByCustomer,Customer,CustomerName,SalesSchedulingAgreementItem,Material,MaterialByCustomer&$format=json. I have updated the question with the SDK version and log requests which gets printed.

Comment: So, you mean the issue is about how the single quotes are put in the generated URL: that fails with `%27`, and that succeeds with `'`.

Comment: I assume the problem is that `'` becomes percentage-encoded to `%27` and then **double encoded** to `%2527`. This double-encoding is a bug and can not be understood by the OData service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (22.03.2021)**

With the [release of SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java) `3.41.0` this week we'll enable support for read operations in OData batch requests on the type-safe API. Please find the chapter in [the respective documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#batch-requests).
Example:

```java
BusinessPartnerService service;
BusinessPartnerAddress addressToCreate1;
BusinessPartnerAddress addressToCreate2;

BusinessPartnerFluentHelper requestTenEntities = service.getAllBusinessPartner().top(10);
BusinessPartnerByKeyFluentHelper requestSingleEntity = service.getBusinessPartnerByKey("bupa9000");

BatchResponse result =
    service
        .batch()
        .addReadOperations(requestTenEntities)
        .addReadOperations(requestSingleEntity)
        .executeRequest(destination);

List<BusinessPartner> entities = result.getReadResult(requestTenEntities);
BusinessPartner entity = result.getReadResult(requestSingleEntity);
```

---

**Original response:**

I'm from the [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/) team. Generally we recommend our users to [generate classes for their OData service interactions](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java). This way you can easily make sure that requests are according to specification, while type safety is taken care of.

Unfortunately I cannot help you with the API of `BatchRequestBuilder`, `BatchRequest` or `BatchResult` because they are not directly a part of *SAP Cloud SDK* and not maintained by us. Instead we suggest our own request builders.

---

If the generation of classes, as linked above, is not an option for you, then I would suggest to try our expert API featuring the *Generic OData Client* of *SAP Cloud SDK*. This is the code that we would also use internally for our generated request builders:

```java
String servicePath = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/YY1_QUANTITYCONTRACTTRACKI_CDS";
ODataRequestBatch requestBatch = new ODataRequestBatch(servicePath, ODataProtocol.V2);
Map<Contract, ODataRequestRead> batchedRequests = new HashMap<>();

// iterate over contracts, construct OData query objects and add them to the OData batch request builder
for (Contract contract : contracts) {
    String entityName = sapConfig.getEssentialsContractListEntity();
    String serviceUrl = sapConfig.getEssentialsContractServiceUrl();
    StructuredQuery structuredQuery = StructuredQuery.onEntity(entityName, ODataProtocol.V2);

    structuredQuery.select("SalesSchedulingAgreement", "PurchaseOrderByCustomer", "Customer", "CustomerName", "SalesSchedulingAgreementItem", "Material", "MaterialByCustomer");
    structuredQuery.filter(FieldReference.of("SalesSchedulingAgreement").equalTo(contract.getSchAgrmntNo()));
    structuredQuery.filter(FieldReference.of("PurchaseOrderByCustomer").equalTo(contract.getCustRefNo()));

    String encodedQuery = structuredQuery.getEncodedQueryString();
    ODataRequestRead requestRead = new ODataRequestRead(serviceUrl, entityName, encodedQuery, ODataProtocol.V2);
    batchedRequests.put(contract, requestRead);
    requestBatch.addRead(requestRead);
}

// execute the OData batch request
ODataRequestResultMultipartGeneric batchResult = requestBatch.execute(httpClient);

// extract information from batch response, by referring to the individual OData request references
for( Map.Entry<Contract, ODataRequestRead> requestMapping : batchedRequests.entrySet() ) {
    ODataRequestResultGeneric queryResult = batchResult.getResult(requestMapping.getValue());
    List<Map<String, Object>> itemsForQuery = queryResult.asListOfMaps();
}
```

Kind regards

Alexander

Comment: Thanks. the above solution worked. I can see the tag @Beta in the Structured query class.  Will this get changed??

Comment: Correct. Most classes of the Maven module `com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel:odata-client` are `@Beta` annotated, indicating that some public API may be subject to changes still. As of today this API above is the only option to read OData read responses from a batch result for **OData V2**. Will this get changed? Yes, most certainly. Either the **OData V2** request builder API will be extended or the **Generic OData Client** (here) will be non-beta. Unfortunately I can't promise a schedule for that. Would such change be critical / urgent for your project?

Comment: Yes. this is critical as I am using this in our project to make the functionality stable. Can this issue be resolved If I use Odata Generator -VDM Model?? Please suggest

Comment: @ArunKumar, we have it in the backlog and as you plan this for production I re-prioritized this to the top. Do you have a time-frame to have this productively released to match your plans? I'll see what we can do then.

Comment: We have a release planned around Mid Feb and a dev deadline by first week of Feb. If this can be released around that time, It will be great!  The other question of using Odata generator - vdm model as an option, will it work ?

Comment: @ArunKumar, I think further discussion is better to happen internally. Can you, create and issue in our repository? You can also find me in the People portal and approach to discuss how we can aid with deadlines and your plans.

Comment: Please notice the updated response. The release will be public by end of week.

Answer (score 1):

**For your information**: with the [release of SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java) `3.41.0` we enabled support for read operations in OData batch requests on the type-safe API. Please find the chapter in [the respective documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#batch-requests). You would no longer need to use the *Generic OData Client* of *SAP Cloud SDK* as suggested in [the other response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65740457/9350514). Example:

```java
BusinessPartnerService service;
BusinessPartnerAddress addressToCreate1;
BusinessPartnerAddress addressToCreate2;

BusinessPartnerFluentHelper requestTenEntities = service.getAllBusinessPartner().top(10);
BusinessPartnerByKeyFluentHelper requestSingleEntity = service.getBusinessPartnerByKey("bupa9000");

BatchResponse result =
    service
        .batch()
        .addReadOperations(requestTenEntities)
        .addReadOperations(requestSingleEntity)
        .executeRequest(destination);

List<BusinessPartner> entities = result.getReadResult(requestTenEntities);
BusinessPartner entity = result.getReadResult(requestSingleEntity);
```